# Multiplexing in computer screens

Tags: shift-register

How are the wires in computer screens connected? I keep searching up "multiplexing LED" and the only result I find is small led matrices with less than 300 LEDs. This can easily be done with a single shift register. But what if I have millions of LEDs? How are the LEDs on my computer multiplexed?

Also I'm pretty inexperienced so sorry if I messed up.

Comment: Typical computer screens do not have millions of LEDs. The LEDs are a just a backlight. The pixels are TFT LCDs. Does this help?

Comment: @Justme I think that the OP is talking about OLED displays